# How can I remove duplicates from an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code which already works :

```
getAllNew: async (req, res) => { //This code is what gives us only events that are going to happen, and discards the ones in the past.
    try {
      const eventsWithLowestPrice = []
      const eventosconboletos = []
      const events = await User.getF()
      for (const event of events) {
        const date1 = stringToDate(event.fecha_fin);
        const date2 = stringToDate(today);
        if (date1 >= date2 && event.hora_fin > my_time) {
          eventsWithLowestPrice.push(event.id_evento_fk)
        }
      }
      for (const eventWithLowestPrice of eventsWithLowestPrice) {
        const publication = await Event.getOne(eventWithLowestPrice);
        eventosconboletos.push(publication)
      }
      res.json(eventosconboletos)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Error al consultar eventos' })
    }
  },
```

The problem is that the events that I'm getting are duplicates in the final push.

Everything is working, but i don't know first which array is the one holding the duplicates and how to get rid of them.

Comment: @jcalz That's true, I've modified the title. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should check eventsWithLowestPrice if id exist on the array do not push it:

```js
getAllNew: async (req, res) => { //This code is what gives us only events that are going to happen, and discards the ones in the past.
    try {
      const eventsWithLowestPrice = []
      const eventosconboletos = []
      const events = await User.getF()
      for (const event of events) {
        const date1 = stringToDate(event.fecha_fin);
        const date2 = stringToDate(today);
        if (date1 >= date2 && event.hora_fin > my_time) {
            if(eventsWithLowestPrice.findIndex(i => i === event.id_evento_fk) === -1)
                eventsWithLowestPrice.push(event.id_evento_fk)
        }
      }
      for (const eventWithLowestPrice of eventsWithLowestPrice) {
        const publication = await Event.getOne(eventWithLowestPrice);
        eventosconboletos.push(publication)
      }
      res.json(eventosconboletos)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Error al consultar eventos' })
    }
  },
```

this code `if(eventsWithLowestPrice.findIndex(i => i === event.id_evento_fk) === -1)` check if event id does not exist on eventsWithLowestPrice list so this is okey push it to array

I hope I understand your question currently